# move div to index position

Tags: jquery, css

I have three divs on my page.

You can see sample here-

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/YrsAL/2/)

On this page i am fading divs on click. Everything goes fine according to what i assumed.

Now if i click on a div tab, all its siblings are fading Out and fading-In again on show all button click.

When div goes hide, then it comes to left position that is default. But i want that div which i click should go always at middle of the page. So i tried giving it index position of second-child but that is not working.

How can i get index position of second child for moving box at middle?

**jQuery-**

```
$(function () {
        var index = $('.span4:nth-child(2)').index();
        $('.container .row-fluid .span4 ').click(function () {
            $(this).show().siblings().fadeOut();
            $(this).css('margin', index);
        });
        $('.show-all').click(function () {
            $('.span4').fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

Comment: give the div a id when it is clicked and on this id you are setting the button with css in the middle of the page

Comment: @MichaelUnterthurner, But buddy there is no specific div.

Comment: I miss understood you question.. sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should use .position() instead of .index()

```
$(function () {
    var index = $('.span4:nth-child(2)').position().left;
    var left = $('.span4:nth-child(2)').position().left;
    var top = $('.span4:nth-child(2)').position().top;
    $('.container .row-fluid .span4 ').click(function () {
        $(this).show().siblings().fadeOut();
         $(this).css('margin-left', left);
    });
    $('.show-all').click(function () {
         $('.span4').css('margin', "auto");
        $('.span4').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YrsAL/9/

Answer (score 7):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/YrsAL/3/

```
.container{
    text-align:Center;     
}
```

Comment: That is tricky, but how about moving div to index position of second-child? your answer isn't be helpful for me.